# Wordpress Password Saving Functions To Python

Tags: python, php, wordpress, hash

3 weeks back I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325396/how-does-wordpress-store-user-password) on here to understand how WordPress saves passwords to db. Mystical suggested I look at the source code, and I tried to but I am not too good with php so I am trying to convert relevant functions to python. Here is what I have so far:

Python:

```
import base64
from email.encoders import encode_base64
from hashlib import md5

prefix = '$P$B'
salt = 'KcFRBGXE'
password = '^zVw*wSFshV2' #password i enter to login

real_hashed_pass = '$P$BKcFRBGXEWOVYQShBC1edT7f3e3Nca1' #this is stored in wp db

hashed_pass = md5((salt + password).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

for i in range(8193):
    hashed_pass = md5((hashed_pass + password).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()


# for i in range(17):
    # hashed_pass = base64.standard_b64encode(hashed_pass)

hashed_pass = prefix + salt + hashed_pass

print(hashed_pass == real_hashed_pass)
```

Relevant PHP ([full code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0337f74a345aef4419f3af7690fbfab884bb5d9a/wp-includes/class-phpass.php)):

```
<?php

class PasswordHash {
    var $itoa64;
    var $iteration_count_log2;
    var $portable_hashes;
    var $random_state;

    function __construct($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
    {
        $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
            $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
        $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

        $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

        $this->random_state = microtime();
        if (function_exists('getmypid'))
            $this->random_state .= getmypid();
    }

    function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $value = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);

        return $output;
    }

    function crypt_private($password, $setting)
    {
        $output = '*0';
        if (substr($setting, 0, 2) === $output)
            $output = '*1';

        $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
        # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
        if ($id !== '$P$' && $id !== '$H$')
            return $output;

        $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
        if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
            return $output;

        $count = 1 << $count_log2;

        $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
        if (strlen($salt) !== 8)
            return $output;

        # We were kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
        # cryptographic primitive that was available in all versions
        # of PHP in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto in PHP
        # would have resulted in much worse performance and
        # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
        # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
        $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
        do {
            $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
        } while (--$count);

        $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
        $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

        return $output;
    }

    function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
    {
        if ( strlen( $password ) > 4096 ) {
            return false;
        }

        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
        if ($hash[0] === '*')
            $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

        # This is not constant-time.  In order to keep the code simple,
        # for timing safety we currently rely on the salts being
        # unpredictable, which they are at least in the non-fallback
        # cases (that is, when we use /dev/urandom and bcrypt).
        return $hash === $stored_hash;
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the python code produce the same hashed password as the wordpress code. I think the error in the python code is at the commented out loop but I am not sure how to fix it.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
When someone enters their passcode you hash it.

```
$hash1 = hash('ripemd320',$passcode);
$sql =  "SELECT `hash`  FROM `Client` WHERE `Number` = $client LIMIT 1";
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
list($hash2) =  mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM);
if($hash1 == $hash2){unlock the pearly gates;}
```

END OF UPDATE
No 0one should ever save a password in a db.  So when you ask "how WordPress saves passwords to db" the answer is they do not.
Are you working ona Word Press add on or do you want to "save passwords" in the same manner as WP?
Word Press is not the place to copy any PHP coding techniques. 
When you bring Python into the equation I have to think you are not working with WP but want to do it the same was as WP.  That would be a bad idea. 
 
Passwords are not that complicated.   And it only takes a few lines of code. 
When the password is created you save the hash in the user's table. When they login you get the hash from the table, hash the password given and compare the two.

I recommend using only numerical usernames. Then when you get the username you convert it to an integer and SQL injection is impossible.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am trying to learn how WordPress saves passwords to the database. To do that I was reading the WordPress source code. However, since I am not good with php, I am writing relevant functions from php to python just to learn. In the end, I want the python code to produce the same hashed password as WordPress does in the database